# TcpListener(port) got error C# FileSharing

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I try to make FileSharing over TCP/IP which client can send or upload file to server

but when the file sent to server, the server doesn't receive any file

this is my code

FileSharingClient.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.IO;


namespace FileSharingClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static string shortFileName = "";
        private static string fileName = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Title = "File Sharing Client";
            dlg.ShowDialog();
            txtFile.Text = dlg.FileName;
            fileName = dlg.FileName;
            shortFileName = dlg.SafeFileName;
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ipAddress = txtIPAddress.Text;
            int port = int.Parse(txtHost.Text);
            string fileName = txtFile.Text;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendFile(ipAddress,port,fileName,shortFileName));
            MessageBox.Show("File Sent");
        }

        public void SendFile(string remoteHostIP, int remoteHostPort, string longFileName, string shortFileName)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteHostIP))
                {
                    byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(shortFileName);
                    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(longFileName);
                    byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
                    byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
                    fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                    fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
                    fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
                    TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(remoteHostIP, remoteHostPort);
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.GetLength(0));
                    networkStream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

FileSharingServer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileSharingServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public delegate void FileRecievedEventHandler(object source, string fileName);
        public event FileRecievedEventHandler NewFileRecieved;  

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.NewFileRecieved+=new FileRecievedEventHandler(Form1_NewFileRecieved);
        }

        private void Form1_NewFileRecieved(object sender, string fileName)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(                
            new Action(
            delegate()
            {
                MessageBox.Show("New File Recieved\n"+fileName);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer", @"c:\");
            }));
        }



        private void btnListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int port = int.Parse(txtHost.Text);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => HandleIncomingFile(port));
            MessageBox.Show("Listening on port"+port);
        }


        public void HandleIncomingFile(int port)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(port);
                tcpListener.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    Socket handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
                    if (handlerSocket.Connected)
                    {
                        string fileName = string.Empty;
                        NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(handlerSocket);
                        int thisRead = 0;
                        int blockSize = 1024;
                        Byte[] dataByte = new Byte[blockSize];
                        lock (this)
                        {
                            string folderPath = @"c:\";
                            handlerSocket.Receive(dataByte);
                            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataByte, 0);
                            fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataByte, 4, fileNameLen);
                            Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(folderPath + fileName);
                            fileStream.Write(dataByte, 4+fileNameLen,(1024-(4+fileNameLen)));
                            while (true)
                            {

                                thisRead = networkStream.Read(dataByte, 0, blockSize);
                                fileStream.Write(dataByte, 0,thisRead);
                                if (thisRead == 0)
                                    break;
                            }
                            fileStream.Close();


                        }
                        if (NewFileRecieved != null)
                        {
                            NewFileRecieved(this, fileName);
                        }
                        handlerSocket = null;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

in this line (FileSharingServer)

```
 TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(port);
```

and I got a error message in my FileSharingServer which is

```
 Warning 1 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.TcpListener(int)' is obsolete: '"This method has been deprecated. Please use TcpListener(IPAddress localaddr, int port) instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202"'
```

anyone can fix it??
thanks

Comment: Before you close the stream after writing data, you should `networkStream.Flush()`. You should also *never* lock on `this` unless you're prepared for a terrible world of pain when someone else also decides to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the IP address and the port to listen on:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);
```

Comment: thanks
I don't get any error

but when I send to file to server, server doesn't receive any file
I have specified the location in receive file from client..
do you know the problem??

Comment: You should make a new question for that. If the file doesn't exist at all, then `Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(...)` isn't being executed, since that line creates the file if it doesn't exist.